# Что такое замыкание в С++

Tags: c++, лямбда-выражение

Помогите понять разницу между обычной лямбдой и замыканием (я вычитал что лямбды не всегда являются замыканиями).

Меня интересует ряд вопросов:

1. Где-то пишут что замыкание это именно захват по ссылке, а где-то что замыкание это когда мы захватываем что-то и не важно как:

```
...

//1. Это замыкание?
[&](int a) { ... };

//2. если да, можно ли сказать что замыкание это когда мы захватывает все внешние объекты или это
//   тоже можно считать замыканием
[&var1](int a) { ... };

//3. И тоже самое с захватом значения. Это замыкание?
[=](int a) { ... };

//4. А это?
[var1](int a) { ... };

//4. А если добавить mutable?
[=](int a) mutable { ... };
[var1](int a) mutable { ... };
```

2. Если все вышеперечисленное является замыканием, является ли замыканием когда мы ничего не захватываем

```
[](int a) { ... };
```

3. Если пункт 2 это тоже замыкание, что тогда не является замыканием?

Что вообще считать замыканием? Кто-то пишет что это когда мы вызываем нашу лямбду.

Comment: Ну в стандарте замыканием (closure) обзываются вообще любые лямбда выражения. С другой стороны, так как С++ не следует никакому академическому формализму, то и никаких замыканий в нем нет, есть только классы с перегруженным оператором (). Так что тут плюрализм.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Данный вопрос хорошо разобран в книге Майерса Эффективный и современный с++ (2016). А именно это глава 6, 221 страница внизу.

> Замыкания (closure) представляет собой объект времени выполнения, создаваемый лямбда выражением. В зависимости от режима захвата замыкания хранят копии ссылок на захваченные объекты.

Лямбда выражение  - это код, то есть то, что написал программист буковками.

то есть, все, что написано в вопросе - это лямбды. Но когда этот код выполняется и создается объект (у которого лямда по факту является `operator()`, а захваченные переменные - переменными этого класса), появляется "Замыкание".

Comment: KoVadim, вы - лучший!

Comment: я просто помню, где прочитал. Но кто то уже влепил минус

Comment: Сочувствую. иногда бывают никак не прокомментированные минусы, и непонятно, что не понравилось.

Comment: да я вот хочу узнать. может действительно есть проблемы, но о них нужно говорить, а не тихо тыкать и бежать радоваться "какой я молодец, минус влепил"

Comment: @KoVadim , маленькое уточнение. То бишь Замыкание появляется на том месте где мы объявили лямбду. И появляется оно после компиляции. Все верно?

Comment: замыкание - это такая сущность (ок, объект) во время выполнения. Она будет создана в том месте, где мы вызываем лямбду в коде. Просто объявить лямбду недостаточно.

Comment: @KoVadim , я имею ввиду что при компиляции создается класс в соответствии с указанной лямбдой. А Замыкание (объект этого класса) создается на месте где была указана нами лямбда. Мы ее получаем `auto lambda = [...](...){...};` и дальше используем как самый обычный объект любого класса. Правильно?

Comment: давайте я попробую сильно проще сказать. лямда - это класс, замыкание - это объект (это грубо, но думаю чуть понятнее)

Comment: @KoVadim , спасибо.